# Create a state-saving accordion

Tags: jquery, url, accordion

I have written a bit of code to create an accordion for my site. My problem is, that I want to enable the user to share (copy-paste) the url with others to get them to see the same accordion item opened as the person who shared it with them. Now, my code works, however it jumps to the location of the accordion item if the page is too long. This creates an ugly effect that I wish to avoid. Ideally I would manipulate the URL without the need to click a link.

Here is what I have now:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vHlJa

HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion">
  <li id="1"><a href="#1">Title 1</a>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>
  </li>
  <li id="2"><a href="#2">Title 2</a>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>
  </li>
   <li id="3"><a href="#2">Title 3</a>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#accordion>li').find('div').hide();

if(window.location.hash) {
   var hash = window.location.hash;
} else {
   var hash = '#1'; 
} 
$('#accordion ' + hash).addClass('open').find('div').show();

$('#accordion>li').on('click',function(){
   $('.open div').slideUp().removeClass('open');   
   $(this).addClass('open').children('div').slideDown().end()   
   .siblings().removeClass('open');
});
```

I created a codepen to show what I mean:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vHlJa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return false` to prevent the default action of the link (scrolling to the anchor).

So you will have to change the hash dynamically :

```
window.location.hash = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
```

You may also want to use a smooth scroll to prevent "jump" to location, but still scroll to the right slide for the user : you can use `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ...});` after the end of the `slideDown()` animation, as follows :

```
.slideDown(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top
    }, 500);
})
```

Here is a jsbin with the modified example : (I used JSBin because I encountered problem with hashs in codepen) :

http://jsbin.com/wahes/1#1

http://jsbin.com/wahes/1#2

http://jsbin.com/wahes/1#3

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. English isn't my first language. I actually want to prevent the "jump-to" effect. Smoothly scrolled or not. However, `window.location.hash = '#' + $(this).attr('id');` does the trick for me, I believe. Thank for that. I'll accept your answer after I did some tweaking when I get home.

Comment: No problem, smooth scroll was just a suggestion, but the `return false` and hash dynamic modification should work for what you wanted ;) but tell me if that doesn't work as expected !